# opengl es 2 just clrears the screen to default color value when using multiple VAOs

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

i'm fairly new to opengl es 2 and since i'm coding IOS apps, i thought id try it!
So I loaded up a default opengl program using the GLKit template in xcode 4 and after fumbling around in the provided code I begun modifying it so that I could draw multiple different kinds of vertex array objects...the problem is only the call to glClearColor seems to produce any results-the whole screen is just grey now:-(
I don't know what is wrong since I checked with many glGetError calls at key places in the code and it always seems to return 0...and I also, to the extent of my small knowledge, follow the steps required to draw with VAOs since when I modified the default code initially to display a plane it worked OK...
So i'm going to be very grateful if you guys could help the newbie!:)

here is a posting of the different relevant parts of the code:

```
//init VAOs:
glGenVertexArraysOES(NUM_VAO, _vertexArrayIDS);
glGenBuffers(NUM_VAO, _vertexBufferIDS);
glGenBuffers(NUM_VAO, _indexBufferIDS);

//init gl object for player:
//setupGLObject(VAO_PLAYER, gCubicVertexData, gCubicIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);   
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubicVertexData), gCubicVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubicIndices), gCubicIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

//NSLog(@"glError after player init : %d", glGetError());
//init gl object for player wall:
//setupGLObject(VAO_PWALL, gPlayerWallVertexData, gPlayerWallIndices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_PWALL]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferIDS[VAO_PWALL]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gPlayerWallVertexData), gPlayerWallVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gPlayerWallIndices), gPlayerWallIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

//init gl object for wall/floor plane:
//setupGLObject(VAO_WALL_FLOOR_PLANE, gPlanePyVertexData, gPlanePyIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_WALL_FLOOR_PLANE]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferIDS[VAO_WALL_FLOOR_PLANE]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gPlanePyVertexData), gPlanePyVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gPlanePyIndices), gPlanePyIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), BUFFER_OFFSET(24));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

drawing function - glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect

```
for (NSString *currentKey in g_renderables) {
    GameObject *currentRenderable = [g_renderables objectForKey:currentKey];

    if (currentRenderable.go_type == LC_FLOOR) {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_WALL_FLOOR_PLANE]);

        glUseProgram(_program);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, currentRenderable.go_mvm.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

        NSLog(@"glError : %d", glGetError());

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(gPlanePyIndices)/sizeof(gPlanePyIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    else if (currentRenderable.go_type == LC_WALL) {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_WALL_FLOOR_PLANE]);

        glUseProgram(_program);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, currentRenderable.go_mvm.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(gPlanePyIndices)/sizeof(gPlanePyIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    else if (currentRenderable.go_type == LC_PLAYER) {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayIDS[VAO_PLAYER]);

        glUseProgram(_program);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, currentRenderable.go_mvm.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(gCubicIndices)/sizeof(gCubicIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
```

matrix computations:

```
float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);


for (NSString *currentKey in g_renderables) {
    GLKMatrix4 thisMvm = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    GameObject *currentRenderable = [g_renderables objectForKey:currentKey];

    if (currentRenderable.go_hasVisual) {

        thisMvm = GLKMatrix4Translate(thisMvm, currentRenderable.go_origin.x, currentRenderable.go_origin.y, currentRenderable.go_origin.z);
        if (currentRenderable.go_type == LC_WALL || currentRenderable.go_type == LC_PLAYER) {
            if (currentRenderable.go_type == LC_PLAYER) {
                if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_MINUS_X) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateY(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f));
                }
                else if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_PLUS_X) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateY(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90.0f));
                }
                else if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_PLUS_Z) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateY(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(180.0f));
                }
            }
            else {
                if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_MINUS_X) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f));
                }
                else if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_PLUS_X) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90.0f));
                }
                else if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_PLUS_Z) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateX(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90.0f));
                }
                else if (currentRenderable.go_orientation == VV_MINUS_Z) {
                    thisMvm = GLKMatrix4RotateX(thisMvm, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f));
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentRenderable.go_type != LC_LINKED_WALL) thisMvm = GLKMatrix4Scale(thisMvm, currentRenderable.width, currentRenderable.height, currentRenderable.depth);
        thisMvm = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(g_currentCam.go_origin.x, g_currentCam.go_origin.y, g_currentCam.go_origin.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), thisMvm);
        //NSLog(@"%f", thisMvm.m[10]);
        thisMvm = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, thisMvm);

        currentRenderable.go_mvm = thisMvm;

    }
}
```

That's it.Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of confusion in the way you understood the glclearcolor.

The main idea is that for every frame you should clear at least the color bit by doing a glclear, it is like cleaning a board after you did your drawings.

The glclearcolor instead instructs OpenGL which color should be used for the whole screen after the clear.

An example of this is the following:

```
glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

This example tells OpenGL to use the red color when a color of the clear of the color_buffer_bit is required.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I meant 'glClear' not 'glClearColor'!  So, 'glClear' is the only gl function call which seems to be producing any results so far...